# php spl_autoload_register() doesn't load a class

Tags: php, class, domdocument, autoload, spl-autoload-register

I have an *index.php* that require *Test1* class trough [spl_autoload_register()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php). In the Test1 class the Test2 class is required with the same autoload but this error occurred:

> **Fatal error:** DOMDocument::registerNodeClass(): Class Test2 does not
>   exist in...

I tried to see if the autoload work writing `$test2 = new Test2();` and it works well. So with other tests I realized that with [registerNodeClass()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.registernodeclass.php) the autoload doesn't include the Test2 class file.

Is there anyone who can help me?

**Test1.php**

```
<?php

namespace Test;

use Test\Test2;

class Test1
{
    function __construct($html)
    {
        $this->dom = new \DOMDocument();
        @$this->dom->loadHTML($html);
        $this->dom->registerNodeClass('DOMElement', 'Test2');
    }
}

?>
```

**Test2.php**

```
<?php

namespace Test;

class Test2 extends \DOMElement
{

//bla, bla, bla...

}

?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

require_once('./autoload.php');

use Test\Test1;

$html = 'something';

$test = new Test1($html);

?>
```

**autoload.php** (it is the same used by Facebook for the php-sdk)

```
<?php
/**
 * An example of a project-specific implementation.
 * 
 * After registering this autoload function with SPL, the following line
 * would cause the function to attempt to load the \Foo\Bar\Baz\Qux class
 * from /path/to/project/src/Baz/Qux.php:
 * 
 *      new \Foo\Bar\Baz\Qux;
 *      
 * @param string $class The fully-qualified class name.
 * @return void
 */
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {

    // project-specific namespace prefix
    $prefix = 'Test\\';

    // base directory for the namespace prefix
    $base_dir = __DIR__ . '/src/';

    // does the class use the namespace prefix?
    $len = strlen($prefix);
    if (strncmp($prefix, $class, $len) !== 0) {
        // no, move to the next registered autoloader
        return;
    }

    // get the relative class name
    $relative_class = substr($class, $len);

    // replace the namespace prefix with the base directory, replace namespace
    // separators with directory separators in the relative class name, append
    // with .php
    $file = $base_dir . str_replace('\\', '/', $relative_class) . '.php';

    // if the file exists, require it
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        require $file;
    }
});
?>
```

Comment: Can we see your autoload.php?

Comment: I added the autoload.php

Comment: Are the classes in the same directory? Or are some in different sub categories?

Comment: The 2 classes is in the same directory

Comment: Why you did not use composer? It comes with autoload

Comment: I have a shared hosting and I can't install it

Comment: Try `$this->dom->registerNodeClass('DOMElement', 'Test\Test2');`. If it works, I'll post a nice answer with explanation and stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

class `Test2` is within namespace `Test`, so in order to do `new Test2()` you must be within the namespace `Test` or you can specify the fully qualified name (ie `new Test\Test2()`) to instantiate the class.

When you call `$this->dom->registerNodeClass('DOMElement', 'Test2');`, DOMDocument does something to the affect of:

```
$extendedClass = 'Test2';
$obj = new $extendedClass();
```

And it doesn't find `Test2` because that code isn't called from the `Test` namespace.
So you would need to pass the fully qualified class name (w/ namespace).

Use: `$this->dom->registerNodeClass('DOMElement', 'Test\Test2');`